# Is there a way to compare two columns of a dataframe containing float values and create a new column to add labels based on it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

df

```
            column_A      column_B
0              0.0           0.0                                    
1              0.0           0.0                                    
2              0.0           1.0                                       
3              0.0           0.0                                     
4              0.0           0.0                                     
5              1.0           0.0
```

I want to create a if condition like:

if(df['column_A'] & df['column_b'] = 0.0:
    df['label]='OK'
else:
    df['label']='NO'

I tried this:

```
if((0.0 in df['column_A'] ) & (0.0 in df['column_B']))
```

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  (df[((df['column_A'] == 0.0) & (df['column_B']== 0.0))])
```

Nothing really gave the expected outcome

I expect my output to be:

```
            column_A      column_B   label
0              0.0           0.0      OK                          
1              0.0           0.0      OK                            
2              0.0           1.0      NO                               
3              0.0           0.0      OK                             
4              0.0           0.0      OK                             
5              1.0           0.0      NO
```

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote all answers here @hakuna_code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in order to create an array with either `OK` or `NO` depending on the result of the condition:

```
import numpy as np
df['label'] = np.where(df.column_A.add(df.column_B).eq(0), 'OK', 'NO')

     column_A  column_B label
0       0.0       0.0    OK
1       0.0       0.0    OK
2       0.0       1.0    NO
3       0.0       0.0    OK
4       0.0       0.0    OK
5       1.0       0.0    NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
#solution if only 1.0, 0.0 values
df['label'] = np.where(df[['column_A', 'column_B']].any(axis=1), 'NO','OK')
#general solution with compare 0
#df['label'] = np.where(df[['column_A', 'column_B']].eq(0).all(axis=1),'OK','NO')

print (df)
   column_A  column_B label
0       0.0       0.0    OK
1       0.0       0.0    OK
2       0.0       1.0    NO
3       0.0       0.0    OK
4       0.0       0.0    OK
5       1.0       0.0    NO
```